# Reading from two files at the same time in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have two files. Say f1 and f2.

```
Contents of f1
pointiac
cadillac
mustang
```

f1 and f2 needn't have the same number of lines

```
Contents of f2
black
blue
```

My loop reads

```
cat f2|while read linex
do
<something to read the next line in f1, which in iteration 1 of this loop is the first line, into a variable liney>
#do something with linex and liney
#terminate when all lines in f2 run out, it doesn't matter if there are unprocessed lines in f1
done
```

I need the code which allows me to read the next line of f1 in a loop that reads the lines of f2.

I understand my example is a little confusing and hard to explain but I did my best. I'd appreciate any help. I'm a total newbie to bash.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do though ?

Comment: I'm unsure as to how to accomplish the thing in the line starting with <something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash    
while true; do
  read -r lineA <&3
  read -r lineB <&4
  if [ -z "$lineA" -o -z "$lineB" ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "1: "$lineA
  echo "2: "$lineB
done 3<fileA 4<fileB
```

Comment: I was able to retro fit your answer to suit me. Thanks man :)